# MATLAB matrix range assignment

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, range, histogram

Is it possible to assign ranges to a matrix.
If you consider the below zeros matrix as a 'grid' for plotting:

```
R = zeros(5,8);
R =
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

So can you treat this matrix as a grid so each x-axis zero can considered as a range? for example `R(5,1)` is a range `0-0.1 seconds`. `R(5,2)` is a range `0.1-0.2 seconds` etc.

Can the range idea also be applied to the columns?

The purpose for this is so I can read cell array data I have already organised into ranges into the zeros matrix to produce a 2d histogram.

[image: Example of my output]

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do. You can for example use `reshape(R,5*8,1)` which would give you all columns of `R` concatenated into a long vector. Alternatively `reshape(R.',5*8,1)` would give you all rows of `R` concatenated into a long vector. (Where `.'` is the transpose operator)

Comment: I have time and data. The time runs from 0-10 seconds with 0.1 ranges in between. Each time value has a data value. Sure I can just use plot but I want a colour density plot due to the volume of data I have. So I am trying to use a histogram where if there are repeated values in the matching ranges this will result in a colour which is proportional to how many data points 'match' in the same range.

Comment: Sorry for the question not being clear! I feel like I need a whole book to describe what I am trying to do

Comment: How about you give us a small example and a sketch of the output you want.

Comment: Please find attached, the sketch of the grid would be a matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you have the times `tt` and the datavalues `val`, where `val(i)` contains the datavalue for time `tt(i)`. In your example you would have

```
tt  = [0.02, 0.22, 0.15, 0.08, 0.27, 0.09];
val = [0.5,  1.4,  2.5,  0.6 , 0.8,  0.3 ];
```

Now you need vectors that represent the time and data ranges that you want (increasing), for example

```
trange   = [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, Inf];
valrange = [0, 1,   2,   3,   Inf];
```

Now you create a matrix of the right size

```
R = zeros(length(valrange), length(trange));
```

You can fill the matrix up easily just by looping over all times you have

```
for i=1:length(tt)
   %// We consider the pair tt(i), val(i)
   %// First find out, in which time range tt(i) lies:
   tind = find(trange > tt(i), 1, 'first');

   %// Now find out, in which value range val(i) lies:
   valind = find(valrange > val(i), 1, 'first');

   %// Now we increase the corresponding matrix entry
   R(valind,tind) = R(valind,tind) + 1;
end
```

Note that the first column corresponds to the time range between `-Inf` to `trange(1)` and the last column to the range between `trange(end-1)` and `trange(end)==Inf`. Simliary for the first and last row.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question.

If you ask, whether it is possible to assign a vector, e.g. `a = [1;2;3]`, to be a column in some matrix `R = zeros(3, 5)`, then this can be achieved by

```
R(:, 1) = a;
R(:, 2) = [4;5;6];
```

Comment: Thank you for your reponse, I don't think my question was clear enough for which I apologise